# Почему при ввода "end" выдает ошибку?

Tags: java

Данная программа выполняет алгоритм, благодаря которому любое число раскладывается на простые множители, при этом все это дело происходит до тех пор, пока не будет введено слово "end".

Все работает, но после ввода "end" вылезает ошибка. Прошу помощи.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        int yesNo, ch;
        boolean tf = true;
        String n;
        Main ent = new Main();
        System.out.println("If you want to exit, write end");

        while(tf == true){
            n = in.nextLine();
            if (n == "end") tf = false;
            else { 
                ch = Integer.parseInt(n);
                ent.calc(ch);
            }
        }
    }

    void calc(int a) {
        int i = 1;
        System.out.print(a + " = ");

        while (a != 1) {
            i += 1;
            while (a % i == 0) {
                if(a / i == 1) {
                    a = a / i;
                    System.out.println(i);
                } else {
                    a = a / i;
                    System.out.print(i + " * ");
                }
            }
        }
    } // calc
}
```

Comment: не надо писать `tf == true` достаточно просто if( tf ). Какая ошибка вылетает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строки в яве нужно сравнивать через .equals():

```
if (n.equals("end"))
```

Comment: Лучше `"end".equals(n)`.